# Timestamp and HTTPS callable - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

After upgrading from `firebase@7.14.6` to `firebase@7.15.0` (as well as up to `@7.16.0`), I now receive a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error when calling `firebase.functions().httpsCallable` with data that contains a timestamp field value obtained via `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. Am I going crazy here or did I miss something from the release notes? Nothing jumped out as to why this would occur.

Comment: Without seeing your code and enough debugging details to reproduce the issue, there's not much we can do.  If you think there is a bug, file your details on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: Please could you share a short version of the code you are using, in order for others to replicate the issue?